How to add x509 certificate and private key in http request in swift?
I want to add x509 certificate and private key in https request in swift. I am new in swift so I need help. I am not sure what should I use to achieve this. I want to call this API
I have tried this till now.
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Security
@objc(AzureProvisionWithCertificate)
class AzureProvisionWithCertificate: NSObject {
  @objc(provisionAndUploadFile:withRegistrationId:withKey:withCertificate:withProvisionHost:withFileNameWithFolder:withModelId:withResolver:withRejecter:)
  func provisionAndUploadFile(scopeId:String, registrationId:String, key:String, certificate:String,  provisionHost:String,  fileNameWithFolder:String,  modelId:String, resolve:@escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject:@escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {

    let url = URL(string: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/\(scopeId)/registrations/\(registrationId)/register?api-version=2021-06-01")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Encoding")
    let bodyData = ["registrationId": registrationId]
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyData)
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            reject("Error", error.localizedDescription, error)
        } else if let data = data {
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            resolve("Response data: \(responseString)")
        } else {
            reject("Error", "No data received", nil)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
  }
}


the private key has no place in the http request. certificate authentication occurs at the transport layer (TLS). to make the communication, you need to add the certificate (and its private key) to the repository that your application uses. the rest is up to the operating system.

Adding a X.509 certificate and private key to a Swift application involves reading the certificate and key from files, creating SecCertificate and SecKey objects.  Creating a SecIdentity from these objects and you'll need to configure URLSession to use these credentials for the request.
Paths to your certificate and key files :

let certPath = "/path/to/device-cert.pem" 
let keyPath = "/path/to/device-key.pem"



I have used   this links for handling Certificates and  Cryptography operations in  Swift .

I have used  below code  to register a device with Azure Device Provisioning Service (DPS) using x.509 certificates in Swift.

import Foundation
import Security

func loadIdentity(certPath: String, keyPath: String) -> SecIdentity? {
    guard let certData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: certPath)) else {
        print("Unable to load certificate")
        return nil
    }

    guard let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData as CFData) else {
        print("Unable to create certificate")
        return nil
    }

    guard let keyData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: keyPath)) else {
        print("Unable to load private key")
        return nil
    }

    let keyDict: [NSString: Any] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 2048,
        kSecReturnPersistentRef: true
    ]

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(keyData as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, &error) else {
        print("Unable to create private key: \(error?.takeRetainedValue() ?? "Unknown error" as CFError)")
        return nil
    }

    var identity: SecIdentity?
    let status = SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(cert, privateKey, &identity)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        print("Unable to create identity")
        return nil
    }

    return identity
}

class URLSessionPinningDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    var identity: SecIdentity

    init(identity: SecIdentity) {
        self.identity = identity
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let credential = URLCredential(identity: self.identity, certificates: nil, persistence: .forSession)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
}

func performRequest() {
    let certPath = "/path/to/your/device-cert.pem"
    let keyPath = "/path/to/your/device-key.pem"
    
    guard let identity = loadIdentity(certPath: certPath, keyPath: keyPath) else {
        print("Unable to load identity")
        return
    }
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: URLSessionPinningDelegate(identity: identity), delegateQueue: nil)
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/[ID_Scope]/registrations/[registration_id]/register?api-version=2021-06-01") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Encoding")
    
    let body = ["registrationId": "registrationId"]
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Request failed: \(error)")
        } else if let data = data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response: \(responseString)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}


performRequest()





Hi @Sampath thank you for answer, I am getting one error i.e. Cannot find 'SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate' in scope I am using macOS Sonoma 14.5 with Xcode 15.3

Follow this SO for for  SecIdentity

The problem arises because SecKeyRef and SecCertificateRef objects exist either in memory or in keychain storage. Only keychain-backed objects have the necessary metadata to form an identity. The public key hash, which is required to match private keys to their certificates, is stored within the metadata, which is only available when the key is stored in a keychain.The solution involves exporting the key from memory, then re-importing it into the keychain, which ensures that the necessary metadata, including the public key hash, is correctly populated.

Once this is done, you can successfully create an identity.
